# mke2fs ignore root_owner

Tags: linux, filesystems, ownership, e2fsprogs

As you [know](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html), if there is no root_owner option, mke2fs use the user and group ID of the user running mke2fs. Let's test it on Ubuntu 22 x86_64 (mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)):

1. Generate image

   mke2fs -t ext2 -I 256 -E 'lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0' -O '^large_file' -O '^huge_file'   -L ext2test  'diskEmpty.img' 102400k
2. Mount image

   gnome-disk-image-mounter -w diskEmpty.img

But only root user can write to this... **Why?**

Let's test root_owner option:

1. Generate image

   mke2fs -t ext2 -I 256 -E 'root_owner=1000:1000,lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0' -O '^large_file' -O '^huge_file'   -L ext2test  'diskEmpty.img' 102400k
2. Mount image

gnome-disk-image-mounter -w diskEmpty.img

Now I can write to my disk.

**Why can't I write to disk without `root_owner` feature?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manpage you linked to explains well in fact that since 1.42 version **the UID:GID of the root directory no longer default to those of the user running mke2fs.**

If, under >1.42 version you want UID:GID of the root directory to be those of the user running mke2fs, you must explicitly specify `root_owner` as part of the feature list eventually omitting its uid:gid optional parameters.

This is a consequence of a patch from T. Ts'o ([mke2fs: don't set root dir UID/GID automatically](https://yourcmc.ru/git/vitalif/e2fsprogs/commit/dc9cc7006a61d0ef82ee4e1dee133998c6040765)) which explicitly instructs to:

> Add the "-E root_owner[=uid:gid]" option to mke2fs so that the user
> and group can be explicitly specified for the root directory.  If the
> "=uid:gid" argument is not specified, the current UID and GID are
> extracted from the running process, as was done in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The new file-system's root is owned by root. With default permissions, only root can write to it. Your session user is most likely an ordinary user (UID 1000 probably).